# Sublime Text 3 - Emmet shortcut for HTML 5 not working.

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, emmet

I have recently downloaded sublime text 3 and installed emmet. The issue that I am having is that when I write the short code for HTML 5 and press tab, it doesn't work. This method was used in sublime text 2 and it worked. Does anyone have any solutions to this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you write and press tab?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

type `!` and then press **Tab**.
found the answer on [cheatsheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)

Comment: what about the older html:5??

Answer (score 6):

Text editor doesn't know what shortcut to expand until you save new file as *.html or change the syntax (bottom/right), because new document starts in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you are looking for something like [Html Boilerplate](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML%20Boilerplate). This package generates a full html5 structure just by typing

```
htmlboiler
```

and pressing **TAB**

**EDIT:** Just found the answer in the [Emmet official cheatsheet](http://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/); just type

```
!
```

And hit **TAB** (Yes, just the exclamation character).

Comment: Of course not, what he want is `div.my-class>ul>li*5` then proper HTML will get expanded

Comment: Exactly what @aokaddaoc said. Thankfully I moved on to use Atom editor which allows me to do just that after installing emmet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an extension. Just either open an html file, save it as an html file, or hit ctrl + shift + P then type "html" and hit enter to select "Set Syntax: HTML"

Then, simply type "HTML" followed by either tab or ctrl+space.

Answer (score 0):

@ayek is correct, all you need to do is set the document type to HTML; once you do, you can then type "html" and hit tab. Good luck, and happy coding. -KW

Comment: This isn't answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file (no need to save or type anything yet).  From the menu, `View > Syntax`, then select `HTML`.  Now type `'html'` and press `TAB`.

The following appears:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This didn't need any extra plugins - standard out-of-the-box Sublime 3 functionality :)

Answer (score -1):

The above answer was the unique correct, that worked:
Create a new file (no need to save or type anything yet).
From the menu, View > Syntax, then select HTML.
Now type 'html' and press TAB.